# Creating a simple table using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm making a table using mostly Jquery and [DataTables](https://datatables.net/)

I'm getting an error when calling `$('#dataTable').dataTable();` but I don't see why this happens since [I see my table correctly displayed](https://i.gyazo.com/f0c1a48cf75951ae4cfb38b156f968e8.png) **but the DataTable script don't work so the table stays normal, instead having pagination,etc...**

This is the error:

> jquery.dataTables.js:1197 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'mData' of undefined
>       at HTMLTableCellElement. (jquery.dataTables.js:1197)
>       at Function.each (jquery-1.9.1.js:648)
>       at init.each (jquery-1.9.1.js:270)
>       at HTMLTableElement. (jquery.dataTables.js:1194)
>       at Function.each (jquery-1.9.1.js:648)
>       at init.each (jquery-1.9.1.js:270)
>       at init.DataTable [as dataTable] (jquery.dataTables.js:869)
>       at DisplayTable (accounts.js:19)
>       at TypesChanged (accounts.js:168)
>       at HTMLDocument. (accounts.js:171)

HTML:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
        <thead class="dataTableHead">
        <tr>
            <%--JSON ARRAY CREATES THE TABLE--%>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot class="dataTableFooter">
        <tr>
            <%--JSON ARRAY CREATES THE TABLE--%>
        </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody class="dataTableBody">
        <%--JSON ARRAY CREATES THE TABLE--%>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var types = [];
var amountOfDayEnds = parseInt($('#amountOfDayEnds').val());

function TypesChanged() {
    selectedGroup = $('#group').val();
    switch (selectedGroup) {
        case "DDA":
            types = ["400", "4044", "4045"];
            break;
        case "SAV":
            types = ["300", "310"];
            break;
        case "MTG":
            types = ["700", "710"];
            break;
    }
    console.log("Selected group: " + selectedGroup + ", Types: " + types);
    $('.dataTableHead').empty();
    $('.dataTableFooter').empty();
    $('.dataTableHead').append('<th class="text-center">Day</th>');
    $('.dataTableFooter').append('<th class="text-center">Day</th>');
    var columnNames = [];
    $.each(types, function (index, value) {
        columnNames += '<th class="text-center">Type ' + value + '</th>';
    });
    $('.dataTableHead').append(columnNames);
    $('.dataTableFooter').append(columnNames);
    DisplayTable();
}

TypesChanged();

function DisplayTable() {
    var data;
    //Table
    $('.dataTableBody').empty();
    for (var i = 1; i <= amountOfDayEnds; i++) {
        data += '<tr align="center">';
        data += '<td>' + i + '</td>';
        $.each(types, function (index, value) {
            data += '<td>' + '<input class="text-center amountOfAccounts" type="number" value="0" name="amountOfAccounts-' + value + '"  data-error="Please, insert a value"  required></td>'
        });
        data += '</tr>';
    }
    $('.dataTableBody').append(data);

    $('#dataTable').dataTable();
}
```

Comment: ***hello darkness my old friend....***

Comment: can you please share your complete code